# How can I generate xml file from mysqldump and where can I find this file?

Tags: mysql

I need to generate xml file from mysqldump and get the path for this file
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqldump` option `--xml`  will allow you to write a dump output as an XML file.  This file will be created on the client side (your computer), in a path expressed by you.  If no absolute path is given, the file will be created in the current working directory.

- [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml)